# HDRI not working properly

Tags: hdri

I was following CG Fast Track's beginner tutorial until the part where he goes and turns off Scene World and increases the World Opacity to max, i did the same but in my end it was all black. I even open a new project to try again and the same thing happen, the background becomes all dark instead of showing the hdri image.

Here's before the world opacity is maxed:
[image]

Here's after it's maxed:
[image]

Any idea how to solves this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Could be a GPU driver issue, but I've never seen this problem before.

Comment: Yeah, probably its to do with my laptop not being that great, i searched around and also found nothing like this. Guess I will live with this until i buy a new pc, its not too much of  a big problem. Thanks for the help